# Close button for div, accessing ID using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, button

I want to create a close button for some of my popup DIVs.
Each one pf them have a particular ID and my idea is to set the CSS 'display' to 'none', based on the Div ID being closed.

The following example is not working. I'm wondering why...

Java Script

```
function CloseDiv(element) {
    var id = $(element).closest('div').attr('id')
    alert(id)  // It's returning the correct id
    $(id).css("display", "none");
}
```

Html

```
<span id='close' onclick='CloseDiv(this)'>x</span>
```

Comment: Try to use only one unique id by page. Change `id="close"` by `class="close"` . @Anoop Joshi show you the right way to hide your div :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to extract the id and make the div hide. You can have a direct selector and makes the div hide.

```
function CloseDiv(element) {
    $(element).closest('div').hide()
}
```

`.hide()` is equivalent to `.css("display", "none");`

You can also remove the inline function call with jquery like this,

```
$(".close").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").hide();
});
```

Note that I've used class instead of id selector, in case you have multiple elements

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
$(id).css("display", "none");
```

to

```
$('#' + id).css("display", "none");
```

or better yet, use

```
$('#' + id).hide();
```